# Proper way to set an AlpineJs variable using value from a select tag

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I need to change the value of `myData` variable to whatever is the current value of the `select` tag.

I am currently using this and it works but is there a cleaner way in Alpine for doing this?

```
<div x-data="{ myData: []}">

    <select id="mySelect" @change="myData = document.getElementById('mySelect').value">
        <option>2021</option>
        <option>2022</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using `x-model`. So the cleaner version of the above code is simply:

```
<div x-data="{ myData: []}">

    <select x-model="myData">
        <option>2021</option>
        <option>2022</option>
    </select>

</div>
```